# Codesign Failed on app validation in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, alamofire, codesign

I had installed Alamofire using pods and was able to work with it well in swift 3. After I had completed the project, I had validated the project in the organiser window of the Xcode. While validation i'm getting an error that says "code sign failed" and this message comes up when Almofire is under going the codesigning process. What could be the problem?[These were the error messages thrown 1 &](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5I0M.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqU3S.png)

Comment: To start with obvious questions: do you have Apple Developer's keys to sign builds installed on your Mac? Can you sign other applications on the same machine?

Comment: S. I can sign other applications

Comment: 1) Has this bundle ID already appeared on Apple's site? Or do you use wildcard App ID? 2) What is inside Show Logs? Maybe there would be some more details on the error you get. **Update**: I missed there is a link for second image

Comment: It's not wildcard signed. I've uploaded the error log picture in the question. But. Can a bundle id start with "io"?